# In C# how do I select the current item

Tags: c#, listview

I am working on a program that is using a listview with several items that it runs through with a foreach loop. How do I get the listview to highlight the current item?

The code I'm trying so far is:

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvActions.Items)
{
    // clear list view items and select the current item
    lvActions.SelectedItems.Clear();
    lvActions.EnsureVisible(lvi.Index);
    lvi.Selected = true;
    lvi.Focused = true;
    lvActions.Refresh();

    // Execute function on current item
    myFunction(lvi.Text);

    // Pause foreach for 3 seconds
    Stopwatch delayWatch = new Stopwatch();
    delayWatch.Reset();

    while (delayWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 3000)
    {
        delayWatch.Start();
        Application.DoEvents();
        delayWatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

there are some interesting threading issues related to your code.

From what I can tell you want to wait 3 seconds and then highlight some items on the list.

I would do it different in order to avoid some threading issues.  Something like this.

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 3000;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    t.Start();

    //add then 
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(ListViewItem i in itemsToSelect)
        {
           i.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SelectedIndex is throwing an error. It looks like the SelectedIndex property doesn't exist for listviews.

Comment: sorry, I was looking at ListBox. List view allows multi select. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx I will update the code.

Comment: every tick select all items? I think that you should use "yield" implements for delegation (event).

Answer (score 0):

@madmik3's solution works fine if your `ListView` never changes it's items. If it does, the code will fail, as you can't `foreach` over a collection and update it at the same time.

I can give a code sample, but if your listview never changes I won't worry about it